# Second tr tag is being displayed above first tr tag

Tags: html

I have a table, inside that table I have a `tr` tag and this `tr` tag contain two separate `td` tag in which first `td` tag contains `img` tag and the second `td` contain the whole new table. further, this table has two different `td` tags. Now when I am trying to add a new `tr` tag inside the first table it should be added below the first `tr` tag but it is being shown above the first `tr` tag.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS56K-U4En-hLXTl1y1ZLG0aZ4ZaiJagJtkkHv1FA4kjst1k-iKgw" style="height: 50px;width: 50px; border-radius: 50%" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; color: blue">First Inner td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 10px;color: lightslategrey">Second Inner td </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>This Should Display After First Row</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also it sounds as if you are using tables for layout purposes - don't do that, they should only ever be used for tabular data

Comment: Your html is invalid - all you need to do is add a td element with colspan="2" inside that last tr and it will work as you want, but again, I would say this shouldn't be in a table

Comment: Thanx Pete let me check with your suggestion

Comment: Great @Pete it's working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the `<td>` tags for the second `<tr>`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS56K-U4En-hLXTl1y1ZLG0aZ4ZaiJagJtkkHv1FA4kjst1k-iKgw" style="height: 50px;width: 50px; border-radius: 50%" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900; color: blue">First Inner td</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-size: 10px;color: lightslategrey">Second Inner td </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <!-- added this -->
      This Should Display After First Row
    </td> <!-- added this -->
  </tr>
</table>
```